# Path environment variable accessible from normal command line but not from a command line opened with administrator privilege

Tags: windows

I have a folder that I have placed in the path environment variable (windows 7) such that I can run my python programs from any directory (using `python -m <python.py>`). Recently I have noticed that the command does not work when I open a command line as administrator but does when I open as a regular user.

Does anybody know why this might be the case and how I can fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this answer by pcmind would be your best bet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685699/windows-7-environment-variable-not-working-in-path

### copied from link above:

I had exactly the same problem, to solve it, you can do one of two things:

- Put all variables in System Variables instead of User and add the ones you want to PATH

Or

- Put all variables in User Variables, and create or edit the PATH variables in User Variable, not In System. The Path variables in System don't expand the User Variables.

If the above are all correct, but the problem is still present, you need to check the system Registry, in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment, to make sure the "PATH" key type is REG_EXPAND_SZ (not REG_SZ).